# convert hyperlink to text in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to convert the web column to plain text. Thanks in advance

i used `tools.ignore_hyperlink` but it gave me error, saying list index

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import tools


data = pd.read_csv('https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/shanebucket/downloads/uk-500.csv')
# set a numeric id for use as an index for examples.
data['id'] = [random.randint(0, 1000) for x in range(data.shape[0])]

data = tools.ignore_hyperlink(data, ['web'])
print(data.head())
```

Comment: what do you mean by plain text?  These values are treated as strings.

Comment: Please use SOs Markdown to make your text more readable (indent code by 4 spaces e.g.).

Comment: i meant to say string (instead of plain text)

Comment: the link is a string. You mean that you want to convert the content of the csv file to a string?

Comment: the column 'web' values are strings, that are hyperlinks, i would like to remove the hyperlinks. sorry for the confusion

Comment: So, data has a column called 'web'. The elements of data['web'] are hyperlinks, correct?

Comment: correct, data is a dataframe with a column 'web' with  hyperlinks

Comment: What happens if you do data['web'].astype('str')?

Comment: i tried and still showing hyperlinks

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type using dtypes. It is object/string, there is no hyperlink dtype. The reason you see the web column as hyperlink is most likely because of the IDE displaying the string as hyperlink, as it auto detects "http://"

```
data.dtypes
```

If you are using Jupyter notebook you can type disable auto hyprelink

```
%%javascript
Jupyter.utils.autoLinkUrls = function (txt) {
    return txt;
}
```